# Error with tool 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'boundingBox'

Tags: pyqgis

I have a bespoke tool that takes a point input with multiple house prices and takes an average for the prices contain within polygons. The tool usually works fine but we have used a different house price input which appears the same as what we have previously used. The error read:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/*****/.qgis2/python/plugins\*****\dist_price.py", 
line 51, in run
self.copy_features_in_catchment()
File "C:/Users/*****/.qgis2/python/plugins\*****\dist_price.py", 
line 132, in copy_features_in_catchment
in_cmnt = self.check_pt_in_catchment(src_feat, 'A')
File "C:/Users/*****/.qgis2/python/plugins\*****\dist_price.py", 
line 264, in check_pt_in_catchment
fids = index.intersects(pt_geom.boundingBox())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'boundingBox'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pt_geom` is null, so you can't call its `boundingBox` property.
You must either filter for nulls before calling this part of the code, or you should find and fix the reason why you got a point with a null geometry.